# My PHP script is giving me very slow upload speed ~400kbps on my localhost using XAMPP server

Tags: php, post, ftp

This is my form :

```
<form name="fileup" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="image" title=" "/>
                <input style="position:absolute; float:right;"type="submit" value="Upload"/>
            </form>
```

And that's the PHP:

```
    session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 

   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
      if($file_name=="")
          echo '<script>
                    alert("No File Selected");
                    window.location.href="index.php";
                </script>';
      else if(empty($errors)==true and !$file_size==0){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
```

While text (using another form) and small files have no problem, large files ~500M uploaded from clients on the same WLAN start at ~1Mbps and then commence at ~400kbps. However, uploads from my own computer happen almost instantaneously. I am a beginner and am using XAMPP server on my windows machine.

These are the modifications i made to the php.ini file:

```
> max_execution_time=120    
> post_max_size=16000M
> upload_max_filesize=8000M
```

Please Help.

Will shifting to another protocol like FTP help?

Comment: Using protocol lighter and designed for heavy file transfer would surely reduce overhead that means less data to be transferred. The problem maybe reside not in the php rather than in the number of apache processes that serve the socket (the bottleneck), because an upload of 500MB causes heavy fragmentation of packets.

Comment: So, could you tell me how i could improvise?

Comment: to me the problem stands in the apache config. try read and apply changes as suggested here  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-apache-web-server-performance .